# Constrain width of UIStackView arranged views inside UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uistackview

I have embedded a UIStackView inside a UIScrollView. When I add a view as an arranged subview to the UIStackView, its width expands beyond the frame and causes a horizontal scrollbar to appear, even when I add horizontal width layout constraints. **I do not want the UIScrollView to expand horizontally**.

The code for programatically creating the UIStackView inside the UIScrollView in `viewDidLoad`:

```
_scrollView = [UIScrollView new];
_scrollView.delegate = self;
_scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
_scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
[self.view addSubview:_scrollView];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[scrollView]|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterX metrics:nil views:@{@"scrollView": _scrollView}]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[scrollView]|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterX metrics:nil views:@{@"scrollView": _scrollView}]];

// configure stackView
_stackView = [UIStackView new];
_stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
_stackView.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical;
[_scrollView addSubview:_stackView];
[_scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[stackView]|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterX metrics:nil views:@{@"stackView": _stackView}]];
[_scrollView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[stackView]|" options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterX metrics:nil views:@{@"stackView": _stackView}]];
```

Then I add my custom view, and an AutoLayout constraint to limit the subview's width to the stackView's:

```
CustomView *customView = [CustomView loadFromXib]; // helper to load from xib
[_stackView addArrangedSubview:customView];
[_stackView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[customView]|" options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing metrics:nil views:@{@"customView": customView}]];
```

However, the resulting CustomView is about double the width of the frame. None of the IB-set constraints in CustomView have fixed widths, so I would expect the content to resize to fit the frame. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Constraining the stack view like that tells it to take up the scrollviews full `contentSize` which is going to cause the scrollview to expand its `contentSize` to fit however wide the stack view wants to be.  If you don't want the scrollview to scroll horizontally then constrain the stack view to be the same width as the scrollview's superview

Comment: @dan, to do that, would I just add the constraint to `self.view` instead of `_scrollView`? That doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: I don't use the visual constraint format very often but I think you can do `@"H:|[stackView(==view)]|"`, add `@"view": self.view` to the views dictionary and add the constraints to self.view

Comment: @dan, that did the trick! Thanks so much. There's one more issue that I could use some help on - now the CustomViews are appearing on top of each other, instead of one after another, as if they don't have a height. (They don't add extra height to the scrollView, either.) The CustomView doesn't have a fixed height but all of its subviews have intrinsic heights or heights set with AutoLayout.

Comment: I've never used stack view so I don't really know what would cause that issue.  I would create a new question for it though.